# Get help/examples/documentation from jdk folder

Tags: java, java-8

I have Java practical exam in few days.
We have to write programs on notepad, and execute them through cmd (using jdk).
So my question is, is there any way that I can access help/documentation in JDK folder? All I want is syntax and method names, etc.

This is because in last exam, I lost all my marks because I wrote

`public class abc extends applet`

instead of

`public class abc extends Applet`

The compilation error wasn't helping. If I had access to the syntax, this wouldn't have happened.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have it in the JDK folder? There is a [full API documentation online](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) as well as a [language documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/index.html). You can [download the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html), if you need it offline.

Comment: @Holger it's an exam, so no, I cannot access the internet, or take downloaded documentation with me. All I will be having is offline computer, jdk folder and notepad.

Comment: That’s a strange prerequisite. If it’s a standard JDK, i.e. containing the `src.zip`, you can regenerate the entire API documentation from it. It’ll only take some time and hard disk space…

Comment: @Holger it's not a strange prerequisite in China. give you a notepad & jdk and nothing else.

Comment: @holi-java: it’s still strange. What is such an exam intended to prove? That you can master situations that you will never encounter in real life? Ok, some people consider this the definition of school…

Comment: @Holger Hi, Holger.You may feel ridiculous. but I can only say that each country's education system is different.

Comment: @Holger articles, words and almost everything must be remember, understanding and explaination on school in China.

Comment: @holi-java: well shouldn’t we reject this question then, as any answer, telling how to get the information instead of remembering it, contradicts the spirit of such exams?

Comment: @Holger yes, you are right. but teachers of computer science will not tell you there is a tool can get the information and even they also don't know it in school. you can only find the answer by yourself.

Comment: @Holger and holi-java I am from India. And I completely agree with holger. We students here have to focus on silly things like case sensitive words and syntax instead on working on the actual code. In real life situation, we would be using a IDE, which takes care of all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the JDK contains the file `src.zip`. Since this is on option that can be turned off during installation, it’s not possible to predict whether it will be there, but it’s on by default.

If the file is there, you can use it to generate almost the same documentation you find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

First extract the files. In theory, `javadoc` could read them directly from the zip file, in practice, it doesn’t work.

On windows, use

```
mkdir classes
cd classes
path-to-jdk\bin\jar xf path-to-jdk\src.zip
cd ..
```

Second, generate the documentation

```
mkdir doc
path-to-jdk\bin\javadoc -d doc -sourcepath classes -classpath path-to-jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar -subpackages java:javax
```

Afterwards, the file `doc\index.html` contains the starting point of the API documentation, equivalent to the one linked above.

It’s a challenge to read them if you don’t have a browser, but actually, it’s always present, i.e. if you click on the “Show Help” menu item in Notepad, it’ll open a browser. If that’s a too obvious rule bending, you can use the “Open File” dialog instead. Just enable “All Files” and the preview window, and it will show the contents of HTML files if you select them, while technically being still in a file dialog of Notepad rather than a browser…

Comment: Thanks for the help. This technically didn't worked, but as you said, I googled about getting documentation from src.zip, and found an easier method. [link](http://java-demos.blogspot.in/2012/11/create-your-own-javadoc-from-command.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using `javac` command to see the compiling error.
If `JAVA_HOME` environment not set, you can use commands to find the jdk path:

```
//On Linux
echo $PATH

//On Windows
echo %PATH%
```

If you forget the class in which package, you can use `jar` command to find the class:

```
//On Linux
jar -tf $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar | grep -i "applet\.class$"

//On Windows
jar -tf %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/rt.jar | findstr -i -r "applet\.class$"
```

If you don't know method in Applet, you can use `javap` command to dump all visible methods,for example: I want a `resize` method.

```
//On Linux
javap -p  java.applet.Applet | grep resize

//On Windows
javap -p  java.applet.Applet | findstr resize
```

**OR** if you want override some method, you also can use `javap` command to dump all protected methods:

```
//On Linux
javap -protected  java.awt.Component | grep protected

//On Windows
javap -protected  java.awt.Component | findstr protected
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I will be working on a windows 7 machine. What changes to make if I want to run these commands in windows OS?

Comment: @Nik windows has a command [findstr](https://www.mkyong.com/linux/grep-for-windows-findstr-example/)

Comment: Use this on windows `jar -tf "<path-to-jdk>\jre\lib\rt.jar" | findstr /r /i /c:"applet\.class$"`.